# Unitialized object of a class as parameters

Tags: c++, class

I'm writing a program that uses a class for complex numbers. I want to use the function   `void Input(Complex z)` to read the real and imaginary part of a complex number and assign them to the complex number z ( which is the parameter) but I get the error *Uninitialized local variable used* and the warning " Using uninitialized memory".

What should I change?

```
class Complex
{

    float x, y;
public:
    float modul() { return sqrt(x * x + y * y); };
    void setcomplex(float a, float b) { x = a; y = b; };
    void getcomplex() { cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")"; };
    float getreal() { return x; };
    float getimaginar() { return y; };
};

Complex suma(Complex a, Complex b)
{
    Complex c;
    c.setcomplex( a.getreal() + b.getreal() , a.getimaginar() + b.getimaginar() );
    return c;

}

void Input(Complex z)
{
    float a, b;
    cout << endl << "Real part:"; cin >> a;
    cout << endl << "Imaginary part:"; cin >> b;
    z.setcomplex(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    Complex numar1;
    Input( numar1);
    numar1.getcomplex();
}
```

Comment: In `Input`, `Complex z` is passed by value. The `Input` function changes nothing back in `main`, thus `numar1` remains uninitialized. Pass by reference instead.

Comment: I can understand about the warning you mentioned, but where eaxactly are you getting error ? Btw, functions in C++ pass data as value by default. You shoud change your defination of Input fuction to the way @OblivionreinstateOurMonica suggested in his/her answer.

Comment: I can post complete code as answer if you want

Comment: Any reason you don't use [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the state of object you passed to a function and interested in the new state, you need to pass it by reference to the function:

```
void Input(Complex& z)
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5x9GS_).